# Images in custom directory or album iOS phonegap

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, filesystems, cordova-plugins

Using cordova 3.5 for creating app for iPad [IOS 6 and till IOS 8], [not native app]

1. Is it possible to create a separate directory inside Gallery and view it on my phone with selected images stored there?
2. If not at all possible, we can move it to the app specific document folder. But, storing images on app specific document folder, will it increase the size of my running application?

Please help, I am not aware of iOS related file system.

Comment: In iOS app, it is possible. you can create an album in Photo library.

Comment: THanks Sandeep. Can you send me any link or reference. Also, I need to use cordova api's not native. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible  via objective c code, you need to write an objective c class that perform creating, retrieving, saving an album and manages photo in them. After that create a Cordova custom plugin that delegate task to Objective c class.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. But, won't it increase my app size, if I am going to allow the user to capture photos more than 50 and store it in my app document folder. Is there any way of adding a folder outside my application and store images there? Please help.

Comment: @ Vinod yes, in photo library, you can create a album, where you can store your photos clicked by camera app.